# Wygwam - Form & script tags being removed

Tags: wygwam

I’m struggling with `<form>` and `<script>` tags being removed in WYGWAM.

When these tags are added via source in WYGWAM and saved they show up on the page but when you go back into edit the entry they do not show up in Source area.

I tried adding this suggested regex to the config file but it didn’t work:
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/wygwam_deleting_javascript_tags_in_content.

Other Regex examples found on Google didn't work either.

How can I allow `<form>` and `<script>` tags in a WYGWAM field?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - we prefer to keep the add-on name in the question title if the question applies to a specific add-on (even if it's tagged as well). This makes it more obvious what the question is about when browsing the question lists.

Comment: If anyone is having issues with embedding Tweets to your entries, this will fix it.

Comment: @ninjaroll I converted your answer to a comment as it's more appropriate... glad my answer helped you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These tags are stripped out of the editor view because the "Restrict Allowed HTML" setting is set to YES for that field's WYGWAM configuration. Changing this setting to NO fixes the issue.

Go to Add-Ons -> Modules -> Wygwam ->(your toolbar config) and set the "Restrict Allowed HTML" setting to 'no'.